# My WPF icons are displayed very small

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

My WPF icons are displayed very small, as you can see in this image, can you please
suggest what could be the problem? I tried to find some properties related to size but
no success.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem could be the bitmap's resolution. Open the bitmap for example in Paint.NET and in the Resize Bitmap dialog check whether it is 72DPI or 96DPI. A large ribbon bitmap should be 32x32 Pixels at 96 DPI.

By the way, in your screenshot the bitmaps actually look ok. What makes you think they are too small?

Comment: Well I want them to be bigger.

Comment: Well, there may be a gap between what you *want* and what you *can do*. Large ribbon images will always be resized to 32 x 32 pixels.

Comment: Oh I did not know that. I thought I can make them bigger. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WPF uses an unusual resolution of 96 dpi... I'm guessing that your images have not been saved at this resolution.